# PHP convert seconds to cents format

Tags: php

I want to convert seconds to hours cents format with a PHP function.

Example:

I have 5400 seconds (1 hour and 30 minutes) and I want to display 1,5.

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: Have you done anything to solve this problem? If so, please share your findings so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about simple:

```
$cents = round(5400 / 60 / 60, 1);
```